# rails simple_nested_form_for fields_for wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes, actionview, simple-form

So I'm building a form in rails 3.1, using

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for(@person, :url => collection_url, :html=>{:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <%= render :partial => "form", :locals => { :f => f } %>
<% end %>
```

but this line in the partial is causing the problem:

```
<h2>Badges</h2> 
<ul id="certifications">
// this following line is raising the error "wrong number of arguments (4 for 3)"
<%= f.fields_for :certifications do |certification_form| %> 
    <%= render :partial => 'certification', :locals => { :f => certification_form } %>
<% end %>
</ul>
<%= f.link_to_add "Add a Badge", :certifications %>
```

So here is the model:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :certifications, :dependent=>:destroy, :order=>:position
  has_many :certificates, :through=>:certifications
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :certifications, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

The controller is using the inherited resource gem.

What's wrong? Thanks for the help.

Comment: wrong number of arguments (4 for 3), see the second code snippet:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was having the same problem until I realized the gem is out of date with the version on git. I just manually updated the gem files with the ones on git and problem fixed!

Answer (score 11):

imorsi is correct, here's how i did it:

> gem "nested_form", :git => 'git://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git'

I also removed and re-bundled the gem, but I suspect that was not necessary.  don't forget to restart your server after gem installation.

Comment: did this, moved js to `/vendor/assets/javascripts/`, updated `/app/assets/javascripts/application.js` to include `//= require nested_form` and then it worked

Answer (score -1):

I tried that, but didnt work

So i ended up doing "bundle open nested_form" and copy pasted from github